# How to show that unit quaternions are isomorphic to $ O(2;\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory

Please help to solve Exercise 2 from Chapter 3 of Gilmore, "Lie Groups, Physics, and Geometry" which states: "Show that the unit quaternions I, J, K generate a group of order 8 under multiplication. Show that this group is isomorphic to $ O (2; \mathbb{Z} ) $."

$ O (2; \mathbb{Z} ) $ is given in the book and has 8 matrices:

$
\pm \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad \pm \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \quad \pm \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \pm \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$

Sure, the unit quaternions generate a group also of order 8: $ \{ \pm 1, \pm \mathbf{i}, \pm \mathbf{j}, \pm \mathbf{k} \} $.

But, looking at the multiplication rules $ \mathbf{i}^2 = \mathbf{j}^2 = \mathbf{k}^2 = \mathbf{i} \mathbf{j} \mathbf{k} = -1 $ and the above matrices, I can't find a correspondence with $ O (2; \mathbb{Z} ) $ matrices. Just for starting, I should have found that at least three of them squared were equal to minus the identity and I couldn't.

Comment: This is off-topic for two reasons: 1. This is a homework-like question. 2. This is a pure math question.

Comment: The last matrix in your list for $O(2;\mathbb{Z})$ squares to $-1$.

Comment: The identity is unique so we know what that is for sure. And 6 of 8 of those things square to 1, so it can't be isomorphic to the multiplicative group generated by the unit axis quaternions (which only has two things that square to the identity). But just citing the multiplication rules for the algebra is quite vague for a group presentation since as a mere group -1 is just something that squares to 1, and maybe is in the center. As a field we know what -1 is and that rule then tells us what the generators do so by associativity and distributivity and such we know what every quaternion does.

Comment: @MengCheng you are right, thanks. I'll correct that.

Comment: From the matrix representation you gave, $O(2;\mathbb{Z})$ is actually the dihedral group of order $8$, which is not isomorphic to the quaternion group.

Answer (score 2):

Your group of 8 matrices permutes the points $\{(\pm1,\pm1)\}$. Because they are in $O_2$, they do so isometrically, and also faithfully (only the identity matrix fixes all those four points. We have just constructed an isomorphism from your group to the dihedral group $D_4$.

This is not isomorphic to the units $Q_8$ of the Lipschitz order inside $\Bbb{H}$. As observed by commenters, this group has only two elements of order four whereas $Q_8$ has six.

A faithful 2-dimensional representation of $Q_8$ requires complex entries. For example (there are many ways of doing this)
$$
{\bf i}\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cccc}i&0\\0&-i\end{array}\right),
\qquad
{\bf j}\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right),
\qquad
{\bf k}\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&i\\i&0\end{array}\right).
$$